Projective module on finite dimensional algebra
My question: let A be a finite-dimensional algebra, $X_{A}$ be a right A-module, if $X \otimes_{A} -$ is exact, then $X_{A}$ is projective.
I think we need to use the tensor-hom adjunction, and at the same time, it should be important that A is a finite dimensional algebra. Any hint will be appreciated.

Every finite-dimensional algebra is (right) perfect, which by a theorem of Bass is equivalent to the statement that every flat right module is projective.
Here's a proof that goes directly from "finite-dimensional algebra" to "every flat module is projective" without going via other equivalent definitions of "perfect". Which is not to say that it's necessarily simpler than proofs that do go via other definitions.
Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$.
Suppose $X_A$ is a flat right $A$-module, and consider the class $\mathcal{C}$ of right modules $C$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(X,C)=0$. I'll show that $\mathcal{C}$ is the class of all modules, and so $X$ is projective.
Every finite-dimensional module $S$ is in $\mathcal{C}$, since $$\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(X,S)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_k\left(\operatorname{Tor}^A_1\left(X,\operatorname{Hom}_k(S,k)\right),k\right)=0.$$
In particular, every simple module $S$ is in $\mathcal{C}$.
So every product $\prod_IS$ of copies of a simple module $S$ is in $\mathcal{C}$. But since $S$ is finite-dimensional, $\prod_IS\cong S\otimes_k\prod_Ik$, which has $S\otimes_k\bigoplus_Ik\cong\bigoplus_IS$ as a direct summand.  So every direct sum $\bigoplus_IS$ of copies of $S$ is in $\mathcal{C}$.
Since there are only finitely many simple modules up to isomorphism, every semisimple module is in $\mathcal{C}$.
But $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under extensions, and any module $M$ has a radical filtration
$$0=MJ(A)^t\subset MJ(A)^{t-1}\subset\cdots \subset MJ(A)\subset M$$
with semisimple factors.
So every module $M$ is in $\mathcal{C}$, and so $X$ is projective.
